# Using MAX() function with flawed field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, crystal-reports-2008

### SAMPLE DATA

### table 1

```
table.DateTime_From          |         table.DateTime_To
-----------------------------|--------------------------------
01/05/2001 00:00:00          |         01/05/2001 08:00:00
01/05/2001 08:00:00          |         01/05/2001 18:00:00
01/05/2001 18:00:00          |         01/05/2001 00:00:00
03/05/2001 00:00:00          |         03/05/2001 12:00:00
03/05/2001 12:00:00          |         03/05/2001 15:00:00
03/05/2001 15:00:00          |         03/05/2001 00:00:00
07/05/2001 00:00:00          |         07/05/2001 00:00:00
06/05/2001 00:00:00          |         06/05/2001 00:00:00
05/06/2001 00:00:00          |         05/06/2001 00:00:00
07/06/2001 00:00:00          |         07/06/2001 11:00:00
07/06/2001 11:00:00          |         07/06/2001 14:00:00
07/06/2001 14:00:00          |         07/06/2001 00:00:00
```

The table above has properties such as:

1. For each record `table.DateTime_From`   <=    `table.DateTime_To`.
2. A time value `24:00:00` is sadly **sometimes** represented as `00:00:00` e.g. compare `table 2` and `table 3` - this cannot be changed, hence changing this is not even an option.
3. A single record can sometimes have a time value `00:00:00` under both the `table.DateTime_From` and `table.DateTime_To` e.g. as see `table 4`.

### table 2

```
table.DateTime_From          |         table.DateTime_To
-----------------------------|--------------------------------
01/05/2001 18:00:00          |         01/05/2001 00:00:00
```

### table 3

```
table.DateTime_From          |         table.DateTime_To
-----------------------------|--------------------------------
01/05/2001 18:00:00          |         01/05/2001 24:00:00
```

### table 4

```
table.DateTime_From          |         table.DateTime_To
-----------------------------|--------------------------------
07/05/2001 00:00:00          |         07/05/2001 00:00:00
```

---

### OBSERVATION

1. Using `MIN (table.DateTime_From)` gives `01/05/2001 00:00:00`
2. Attempting to use `MAX (table.DateTime_To)` creates a problem because this would give `07/06/2001 14:00:00` - although this should actually have been `07/06/2001 00:00:00` i.e. `07/06/2001 24:00:00`.
3. Remember that `07/06/2001 24:00:00` is represented as `07/06/2001 00:00:00` - hence the problem when using `MAX (table.DateTime_From)`.

---

### QUESTION

1. Is there a way around the problem observed with using `MAX (table.DateTime_From)`, so that I would then be able to get `07/06/2001 00:00:00` - even though its a very poor representation of `07/06/2001 24:00:00`.
2. Or is there some fundamental detail that I am not understanding here ...

Comment: Are you storing the timestamps as strings? You cannot compare these dates meaningfully, because `31/01/2001` would be "greater" than `01/12/2001`.

Comment: the timestamps are not strings. the time-stamps are present in a field defined specifically as a date-time value on an SQL Server table.

Comment: moreover that table is being used by a Service Management System (SMS) hence altering the table is not even an option - assuming that comes up. The SMS is quite fickle hence I usually tend to "ONLY" read data from it ... and then try to use SQL to juggle the selected data.

Comment: 24:00:00 isn't a valid DateTime. SQL Server datetime time portion goes from 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997.

Comment: the timestamp `24:00:00` was included in the explanation to only help people understand what `00:00:00` is supposed to mean in another context within the tables.

Comment: Frankly, what you probably ought to do is make that `DateTime_to` (really, prefixing with datatype?) column _exclusive_, and see about actually updating those dates to the following day.  Especially because if you ever get a range similar to `06/17/2012 12:00:00 - 06/19/2012 00:00:00`, you may not be able to tell what day it's supposed to represent.  And I can't imagine that this works well for daylight savings, if that's possible (ie - the `00:00:00` representation does _not_ exist for some timezones, but `24:00:00` - the next day - _does_).

Comment: @X-Zero good observation about the `DateTime_to` prefixing with datatype. However the reality is that this is not the real field name ... I intentionally called it that in `table 1` so as to convey a meaning idea of what that field is meant for.

Comment: @X-Zero in regards your suggestion of using `06/19/2012 00:00:00` instead of `06/18/2012 24:00:00` ... I have also considered that option but have not yet tried it.

Comment: @N West ... I agree that using `24:00:00` itself is a snag. Hence it makes logical sense that `table 1` itself does not actually contain `24:00:00` ... hence why I included in the explanations that via some twist of logic `00:00:00` can actually mean `24:00:00`.

Comment: @sysuser - You've missed my point slightly - what I was pointing out that, occasionally, when you store a date (say, `06/19/2012 00:00:00`), you won't (necessarily) be able to tell if it's supposed to be _that_ instant in time, or the **next day** (`06/19/2012 24:00:00`...).  Store the instant in time you actually mean, not something that's going to require some sort of weird processing.  **ESPECIALLY** if the rules for whether a `00:00:00` time represents that time, or `24:00:00` (next day) is dependent on an independently update-able column...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a view that does something like this (in SQL Server dialect)

```
SELECT table.DateTime_From
 , table.DateTime_To
 , CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(table.DateTime_From, hour) = 0 
        AND DATEPART(table.DateTime_From, minute) = 0
        AND DATEPART(table.DateTime_From, second) = 0 
      THEN DATEADD(day, 1, table.DateTime_From)
    ELSE table.DateTime_From
   END AS DateTime_From_Corrected
 , CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(table.DateTime_To, hour) = 0 
        AND DATEPART(table.DateTime_To, minute) = 0
        AND DATEPART(table.DateTime_To, second) = 0 
      THEN DATEADD(day, 1, table.DateTime_To)
    ELSE table.DateTime_To
   END AS DateTime_To_Corrected
FROM MyData table
```

and then you can use the `Corrected` columns in your query?

Comment: logic of your code seems similar to what @X-Zero suggested. The only problem is that sometimes `00:00:00` really means `00:00:00`. Yet at other times `00:00:00` means `24:00:00` - hence why am threading carefully with the idea.

Comment: Ok, but how do you tell which time it really means?